# Sidekiq error NoMethodError: undefined method `:send_welcome_email' for "AdminMailer":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, sidekiq

I am trying to send email using Sidekiq like this:

```
AdminMailer.delay.send_welcome_email(1)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `:send_welcome_email' for
"AdminMailer":String
```

I recently upgraded from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.0 and my Ruby version is 2.1.1. After the upgrade we got this issue.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekiq has another syntax. 
You should do like this:

```
AdminMailer.send_welcome_email(1).deliver_later
```

There are examples in "[Sending emails with ActionMailer and Sidekiq](https://gist.github.com/maxivak/690e6c353f65a86a4af9)".

Comment: Thanks nautgrad. But their document says above syntax should work. and it used to work in my older version. Also in sidekiq I can call a class method with delay right? Even that is throwing same error.

Comment: Problem is that ruby don't recognize `AdminMailer` like a class. It thinks that this is string, this is not expected behaviour.

Comment: Oh I see... I guess there is conflict in gems which overrides delay method of sidekiq.Let me try some other way.. Thanks